# How to get nav-pils selection when user submits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm using bootstrap and pug to display a tab view and I want to know what tab the user has selected when they submit. How do I get this? Can I get this in the query? Or can I store it somewhere in javascript? I'm new to html, pug, and javascript

```
form(method='GET', action='locate')
  ul.nav.nav-pills
    li.active
      a(data-toggle='pill') one fish
    li
      a(data-toggle='pill') two fish
    li
      a(data-toggle='pill') red fish
    li
      a(data-toggle='pill') blue fish
input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Comment: When you select a pill a class `active` is applied to the tab. You can use `$('.nav-pills .active').text()` to get the text of selected pill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul.nav.nav-pills li').click(function(){
       var selected_text = $(this).text().trim();
       console.log(selected_text);
   });
 });
</script>
```